# Error trying redirect www to non www using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, web

Im having one problem trying to redirect www to non www, using htaccess.

Thats my .htaccess code:

```
    Options All -Indexes
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews    

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When i access http://www.zipurl.me/developer im redirect to http://zipurl.me/developer.
But when i access my main page, http://www.zipurl.me im not redirected to http://zipurl.me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is those 2 rewrite conditions that are basically blocking home page from being redirected.

Replace your code with this:

```
Options All -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: With this code, i cant retrive PHP POST vars. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can use an additional condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST` to prevent it being redirected for POST requests.